# moment js cannot change date string to new format

Tags: javascript, mysql, momentjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<strong id="ut-open-date">27/06/2014</strong>
```

and I want to read the text/innerhtml and convert its format to "YYYY-MM-DD" so I can insert it into MySQL table. I am using the `moment.js` library and my code is below:

```
var CreateDate = moment(jQuery('#ut-open-date').html()).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
CreateDate = moment(CreateDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

But the code changes `27/06/2014` to `2016-06-03` and I cannot work out why.

I also tried this code with the same result.

```
var CreateDate = moment(jQuery('#ut-open-date').html()).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of `momentjs` you are usin?

Comment: Hi @Rahil Wazir I am using 2.5.1. I solved it by using split. See my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we break down your code step by step you can see where it is going wrong:

```
var CreateDate = moment(jQuery('#ut-open-date').html())
```

This part uses the default constructor to try to parse the date, this is unreliable at best and has been deprecated.  So moment is trying to guess what the date format is here.

```
.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

This is taking what ever was read in step 1 and trying to turn it into a string with the format of DD/MM/YYYY

```
CreateDate = moment(CreateDate)
```

Now you are parsing again without specifying the format so moment is doing it's best to guess

```
.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Now you have told it to turn whatever it guessed the date to be into a string with the format YYYY-MM-DD

Do this instead:

```
var CreateDate = moment(jQuery('#ut-open-date').html(), 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

The `moment(dateString)` form is deprecated you should use the form moment(dateString, expectedFormat) instead.

See moment documentation here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Thanks to athms for link

Comment: Spot on @JackAllan, or var CreateDate = moment(jQuery('#ut-open-date').html(), 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); for the purpose of the example. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to tell `moment.js` what format for date string you want parse by specifying second parameter. See all the [supported format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/). If your format is not listed ([See the Open Issue for NON-ISO strings](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407)), you need to specify the date format parameter.

```
moment( jQuery('#ut-open-date').html(), "DD/MM/YYYY" )
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zLWLU/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `split` as follows:

```
var CreateDate = jQuery('#ut-open-date').text();
var DateArray = CreateDate.split('/');
CreateDate = DateArray[2] + '-' + DateArray[1] + '-' + DateArray[0];
```

Comment: BTW this is not the correct way. See two answers below which is what best suite for you.